# PySimpleGUI : How do I align a button to the right of it's containing window

Tags: pysimplegui

**PySimpleGUI : How do I align a button to the right of it's containing window.**

I searched the documentation and forums. The only thing I could find was to justify all elements in a window. Which is not what I want to do.

All I want to do is to put one button on the right hand bottom corner of it's containing window.

Is this possible?

Comment: Put a `sg.Push()` on left side of your button on the same row in layout. like `layout = [[sg.Push(), sg.Button('CLICK')]]`